# MySQL Add column with default value, Syntax with QUOTES

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing well with mySql, but when it comes to some quirks I am struck.

This is something I used for years successfully

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE " . $Tablu . " ADD " . $Colu . " varchar(" . intVal($Siza) .")";
```

What I want now is just add a DEFAULT value for the new column I am adding.
Please provide a syntax WITH THE EXISTING STRUCTURE of the query. That is with THE QUOTES

I am trying this

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE " . $Tablu . " ADD " . $Colu . " varchar(" . intVal($Siza) .") DEFAULT ('" . $defa . "')";
```

But it is NOT working

I CANNOT understand the without-quotes-mysql game at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done to add `DEFAULT`? Did you try something?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the original to show what I am currently trying

Comment: Tried with a '=' after DEFAULT, tried with 'SET' before DEFAULT, nothing works.

Comment: MySQL is and most of its users are NOT consistent all over the net. The greatest evil is the quotes-no quotes play. The given answer here worked for String field. But the same is NOT working for a memo field. Still looking for a solution..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you query is ok .. you just need to remove those brackets () around $defa.. like this-

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE " . $Tablu . " ADD " . $Colu . " varchar(" . intVal($Siza) .") DEFAULT '" . $defa . "'";
```

Comment: Thank you Manoj. I thought I had tried all alternatives. Anyway, it worked.

Comment: But Manoj, It worked for string field. But with a MEMO field, no luck. Any ideas? 
<code>
$sql = "ALTER TABLE " . $Tablu . " ADD " . $Colu . " Text DEFAULT '" . $defa . "'";
<code>

Answer (score 0):

This might be the correct way to do it.

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE " . $Tablu . " ADD " . $Colu . " varchar(" . intVal($Siza) ." DEFAULT 'default_value')";
```

Comment: Syntax is correct and what you posted latter is also correct but one reson this might not be working is your `$Siza` could be less than the length of `$defa`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value in the quotes itself using

`SET DEFAULT 'value'` OR `SET DEFAULT NULL`

Your query will be like

`$sql = "ALTER TABLE " . $Tablu . " ADD " . $Colu . " varchar(" . intVal($Siza) .")" . " SET DEFAULT " . $defa;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$size = intVal($Siza);
$sql = "ALTER TABLE {$Tablu} ADD {$Colu} VARCHAR({$size}) DEFAULT '{$defa}'";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer